# Is there any easy way (wrapper/dictionary) to convert from Keys enum to SenKeys string?

Tags: c#, dictionary, sendkeys

I need to convert from Keys to strings used in Sendkeys method.
Sample:

Key.Enter to {ENTER}

Is there any easy way to do that? I could not find it.

```
 if (key == Key.Enter)
     SendKeys.SendWait({ENTER});
```

I need tomething that convert ALL keys..
If key == Key.a, I will just send a. But, if it is a command key (ex: Key.Enter) I need to make it upper and add {}.

Comment: In a scenario like this you might want to consider making your own mapping library (if you indeed cannot find one) and also consider dropping into a windowsapi call to just pass the keycode through instead of using `SendKeys` and save yourself all the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Possible way could be wrap the `Key` standard enumerator into a wrapper class, with this approach you can create a `ToString()` method that transform the enumerator value into a string.

Take a look at this example :

**Enum Wrapper Class**

```
class KeyEnumWrapper {
        public System.Windows.Forms.Keys key { get; set; }

        public KeyEnumWrapper(System.Windows.Forms.Keys key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public string ToString() {
            return "{" + key.ToString().ToUpper() + "}";
        }
    }
```

**Client (usage)**

```
  private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            KeyEnumWrapper wp = new KeyEnumWrapper(e.KeyCode);
            SendKeys.SendWait(wp.ToString())
        }
```

Comment: the "{}" is not for all keys (http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx), but thanks for the ideia.

Answer (score 0):

```
Key.Enter.ToString().ToUpper()
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to find out if it is a command key or not, to all Keys. If it is a command key I can do what you said, but it will not work for all keys.

Comment: @Pedro77: may be I don't understand your point. What command keys you gonna process?